# How to find number of columns in MS Word table with document set for right to left

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a MS Word document containing tables with Arabic text (i.e. the document is set for Right to Left). However I am working with this document on a computer set for English. There is a table with multiple rows and 3 columns. In some of the rows all three columns might be merged and in some other may be 2 columns.

I am trying to traverse through the table each row at a time as I want to automatically change some contents in the table if the row has two cells merged or none of the cells merged.

However both the below lines of VBA code throws the error

> "Run time error 5941, The requested member of the collection does not
>   exist"

```
ThisDocument.Tables(1).Columns.Count  
ThisDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
```

The above two lines work perfectly fine on a document with English text i.e. set for Left to Right.

Comment: A possible cause of this error is that ThisDocument is a reference to a different document that contains no tables. Worth being absolutely sure IMO.

Comment: I got the same error with both English and Arabic. Changing ThisDocument to ActiveDocument cleared the error in both English and Arabic.

Comment: @JohnKorchok: I hope the OP is paying attention, but suspect that the problem is not to do with the use of "ThisDocument" per se, because if ThisDocument actually contains a table, the code should probably work. It's more that ThisDocument really is "This document" and not "the currently selected document" - something that is quite easy to confuse when you are testing.

Comment: True. Just to expand this a little, if the document to be revised is a .docm that contains both the macro and the table, ThisDocument should work. If the macro is in one file and the table in another, ActiveDocument is the syntax to use. The language settings don't seem to make any difference.